# Method changing first element in a list only (List passed as a parameter)

Tags: python, list

I have a function that gets the one-hot-bit binary value of a float and it works fine. Now I have to pass a list of float values to another function that iterates over the list and replacing the values in the list by the equivalent one-hot-bit binary value. The iterating function only changes the first element in the list. I am new to python, could someone help or direct me to the correct way?

```
import decimal
import numpy as np
from ctypes import *


def one_hot_bit_val(x) :
    #return answer

def one_hot_bit_List(myList) :
    for n in range(0, len(myList)) :
        myList[n] = one_hot_bit_val(myList[n])
        return myList

B = [0.023, 0.0627, 0.0344, 0.0627]
print (one_hot_bit_List(B))
```

result:

[0.015625, 0.0627, 0.0344, 0.0627]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you misindented your code:

```
def one_hot_bit_List(myList) :
    for n in range(0, len(myList)) :
        myList[n] = one_hot_bit_val(myList[n])
    return myList # <-- here
```

Otherwise you return just after processing the first element.

Comment: I will! waiting for the 10 mins to pass by